# "Have you been swimming?" and "have you just swum?"

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

If I meet my friend as he is leaving the swimming pool, I know I can ask: **Have you been swimming?**

But can I also say **"have you just swum?"** instead of the question above?

If so, do the two questions have the same meaning?

Or, is there any slight difference?

And which of the two is better?

Comment: sports: to go swimming, to go surfing, to go biking etc. are idiomatic, also when referring to the activity. But that does not mean you can't say: Have you just swum? Usually, one would say: Have you just been swimming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible. They have the same objective meaning.

"Have you been swimming" is a question about how you have spent the last period of time. "Have you just swum" is a question about what you have done in that time.

Since swimming is not a telic activity, there is very little difference, but suppose the question was about writing an essay: "Have you been writing your essay" does not presuppose anything about whether it was finished, but "Have you just written your essay" is asking about completion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.